# Translate HTML string to with Attributes applied using Firebase/MLNLTranslate

Tags: html, swift, nsattributedstring, google-translate, firebase-mlkit

Here is my code which is used to convert HTML string to attributed string.

```
extension UILabel {
    func setHTMLFromString(text: String) {
        let modifiedFont = NSString(format:"<span style=\"font-family: \(self.font!.fontName); font-size: \(self.font!.pointSize)\">%@</span>" as NSString, text)

        let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
            data: modifiedFont.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
            options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType:NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
            documentAttributes: nil)

        self.attributedText = attrStr
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to translate the text with attributes applied to it. Below is the code for translation that I'm using to translate the simple string.

```
extension UIViewController {

    func translate(text:String, to:TranslateLanguage, compltion: @escaping ((Bool,String?)->()) ) {
        let options = TranslatorOptions(sourceLanguage: .en, targetLanguage: to)
        let translator = NaturalLanguage.naturalLanguage().translator(options: options)
        perform(#selector(showHudAfterTime), with: self, afterDelay: 1)
        translator.downloadModelIfNeeded(with: .init(allowsCellularAccess: true, allowsBackgroundDownloading: false)) { (error) in
            NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self)
            GlobalAPI.hideLoadingHUD()
            if error == nil {
                translator.translate(text) { (translation, error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        compltion(true,translation)
                    } else {
                        compltion(false,text)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                compltion(false,text)
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func showHudAfterTime() {
        GlobalAPI.showLoadingHud()
    }

}
```

Let me know if need any more description.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `yourLabel.attributedText.string` isn't enough for you? You want to translate piece by piece (where a piece can have a different attribute?)?

Comment: yourLabel.attributedText.string isn't enough. As there would be different range of attributes to be applied to string in different languages.

Comment: Iterate through the attributed and translate piece by piece then? But I wonder what happens in that case, since you loose context.

Comment: I want this translation to display in tableview. So iterating it would not be preferable. Still will you please guide me with some code for that so I can find some better solution from that.